# display listview of files available on any files hosting server in app

Tags: android, android-listview

i am working on android app which will show the files available on any file hosting service in a listview so that I can download them. I am okay with any file hosting service if that works for me. I have tried dropbox but not working for me.please suggest me the code or anything which is regarding this topic. I have even tried the Apache service but didn't work. 
thank you!!!

```
package com.example.mangesh.comp;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ass_bce extends ActionBarActivity {

    DLFiles clientServerInterface = new DLFiles();
    private String localjsonString="{\"data\":[{\"file_name\": \"file.pdf\", \"physical_path\": \"/pic/file.png\"}]";
    private ListView listView;
    private List list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ass_bce);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        new RetreiveData().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ass_bce, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class RetreiveData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>> {

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                JSONObject jobj = clientServerInterface.makeHttpRequest("localhost/man.php");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(localjsonString);
                list = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (jsonArray != null)
                {
                    int len = jsonArray.length();
                    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Array is Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return list;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {

            ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listView.setAdapter(aa);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple API which will take request from the Android app and return a response in JSON containing the files and their path.

For example,

PHP Snippet,

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'get_data') {

            // print the data
            $user = $db->getData();
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["data"]["file_name"] = $user["file_name"];
            $response["data"]["physical_path"] = $user["physical_path"];
            echo json_encode($response);

    }
}
```

at http://anyhost.com/API/api.php accepts a POST request and responses with the following JSON,

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "file_name": "file.png",
            "physical_path": "/pic/file.png"
        },
        {
            "file_name": "file.png",
            "physical_path": "/pic/file.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now simply parse this JSON and show it in your app. See the example here,

[Android Populating a ListView from JSON](http://techlovejump.com/android-poplulating-list-view-from-json/)

Comment: i've done as you said.But still something is wrong I feel. plz have a look on my code and let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I am new to json but familier with php so I couldn`t understand what you said about json part. Still I've tried and  something is wrong and I cant figure it out. plz have a look on my code posted above and let me know where I am going wrong. when I am trying to run this the error says "An error occured while executing doInBackground()" . Help me!!!